Optimal discrete betting strategy
An interesting problem I saw recently: You play a game where you start with $N$ dollars and your goal is to end up with at least $M$ dollars. On each turn of the game, you choose a nonzero integer amount up to whatever you currently have to bet. With probability $p,$ you win the bet and receive that amount; otherwise you lose that amount. You lose the game if you run out of money. The objective is to maximize the probability of reaching $M.$ Formally, a betting strategy is a function $b : \{1,\ldots,M-1\} \to \{1,\ldots,M-1\}$ such that $b(k) \leq k$ is the amount you bet if you currently have $k.$ What is the optimal strategy?
My guess is that if $p \geq \frac{1}{2}$ an optimal strategy is betting $1$ each time, ie. $b(k) = 1$ for all $k,$ and if $p < \frac{1}{2},$ bet everything until you get close enough to $M$ in which case you bet just enough to reach $M,$ ie. $b(k) = k$ when $2k \leq M$ and $b(k) = M-k$ otherwise. (Although the strategy of betting $1$ each time does is not the unique optimal strategy for $p \geq 1/2,$ since betting $d$ each time where $d$ is a common divisor of $N$ and $M$ also yields the same winning probability.)
It is particularly interesting in the case $p=1/2$ whether you can do better than a simple random walk (betting $1$ each time), or probability of $\frac{N}{M}.$ Intuition says that's the best that we can do and we can't be clever by trying to bet more in some turn but I don't know how to show it in this case either.

google for "kelly criterion for betting". It sounds like that is what you are after or some variation of it.

@markleeds  Kelly criterion isn't quite what we want, since Kelly betting maximizes log EV while here we care about maximizing the probability of surviving to $M$ (this game has two absorbing states, $0$ and $M.$) I don't think they are equivalent objectives.

Maybe look at Kelly's derivation and see if it can be modified for M ? I was just putting that out there in case you weren't familiar with it. Note that he's maximizing log wealth so it's implicitly maximizing survival, I would think.

I don’t think its applicable here. Yes I did point out Kelly maximizes log wealth but it’s not really the same. I haven’t checked derivation but I wouldn’t think it can be adapted since different optimizations. First off when $p < 1/2$ or $p = 1/2$ Kelly would recommend betting nothing, as long run you’ll run out of money (assuming there’s no upper limit you stop at). Also I’ve ran simulations of betting a fixed proportion and they don’t do as well as betting 1 each time for $p > 1/2.$ I think the problem is more similar to classic gamblers ruin than betting rules like Kelly.

My only advice I would look at the past research by thorpe or ziemba or both. The game sounds like something pretty practical that one of the gurus in the past would have looked at. Other than that, I can't be helpful. I've looked at Kelly to some degree but, even that has it's problem when doing a lot of trades. Oh, there's also a book on the kelly criterion that covers a lot of ground but unfortunately mine is in storage. That book has many, many papers in it and could cover some variant of what you're looking at.

This is the book that I was referring to but I can't guarantee that it will be helpful. The only certainty is that you'll know what all the references are. https://www.amazon.com/KELLY-CAPITAL-GROWTH-INVESTMENT-CRITERION/dp/9814383139/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1CQLQ4X3IUO6N&keywords=kelly+criterion&qid=1660316971&sprefix=kelly+criterion%2Caps%2C124&sr=8-1
